# Improve hide .php extension with .htaccess--currently file names with hyphens get 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My code works **except** I get a 404 for pages with files containing hyphens (and other special characters).

In other words "www.example.com/page.php" shows up as "www.example.com/pages", but "www.example.com/pages-pages.php" throws a "404 Error - Page Not Found".

My code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

I assume I need to specify special characters are okay, but I don't know how.

Comment: Character class `[a-z]` matches letters from `a` to `z`. If you want it to match a `-` as well, you need to add that to it.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your help! This allowed me to figure it out. I also included numbers and underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe (or @CBroe) I came up with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

The original code allowed only file names with lowercase letters in them, otherwise it would throw  a "404 Error - Page Not Found". In the above code the last line allows files with all letters a–z (upper and lower case) and hyphens and underscores in the names.

I would like to allow special characters, but many of them need to be escaped and I don't know which ones or how to do it (probably just a \). This is good enough for now!